# Angular JS Protect Server Routes

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I've created an angular app for coding challenges using the MEAN stack with passport authentication. The website is done, however users with knowledge of GET/POST can bypass the forms to get all the questions/answers as well as display all user information. I've looked at things like JWT but not sure if thats necessary.

AuthService snippet (if visitor goes to URL: localhost:http://localhost:8080/user/users they will see all user information)

```
service.getAll = function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.get('/user/users', { headers: { 'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache' } } )
    .success(function (response) {
      var users = response;
      deferred.resolve(users)
    })
    .error(function (response) {
      deferred.reject()
    });
  return deferred.promise
};
```

User route snippet

```
router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
User.find({}, function (err, users) {
if (err) {
  res.status(500).json({
    err: err
   });
  } else {
  res.status(200).json(users);
  }
 });
});
```

How can I keep end users from executing my GETS/POSTS via the url?

Comment: The question title is misleading because this is more of a server question than angular.  Angular is a **front-end** framework and you will not be able to use it to stop people from directly accessing the URL's of your API.  What you are asking is how to protect the routes in your server API.  You would need to perform validation using your server-side passport authentication library and render an appropriate response.